# JSON syntax returned from MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an MVC controller that is returning a JSON string. The string is in this format when at the moment it returns to the calling jQuery ajax() function:

```
{\"Data\":{\"@ReportID\":\"8\",\"Parameters\":{\"@DateFrom\":\"8/1/2015\",\"@DateTo\":\"8/31/2015\",\"@VenueIDs\":\"1\",\"@EventTypeIDs\":\"1,10,11\",\"@ReportType\":\"1\",\"@GroupBySubType\":\"False\",\"@GroupByMonth\":\"False\",\"@EventTypes\":\"Concerts,National Touring Division,Booking Agreements\",\"@Venues\":\"MSG - Arena\"}}}
```

When I receive it, it looks like this:

```
{\Data\:{\@ReportID\:\8\,\Parameters\:{\@DateFrom\:\8/1/2015\,\@DateTo\:\8/31/2015\,\@VenueIDs\:\1\,\@EventTypeIDs\:\1,10,11\,\@ReportType\:\1\,\@GroupBySubType\:\False\,\@GroupByMonth\:\False\,\@EventTypes\:\Concerts,National Touring Division,Booking Agreements\,\@Venues\:\MSG - Arena\}}}
```

jQuery no longer likes it because this will not execute:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

I'm invoking the MVC controller like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetSelections",
        data: {
            json: params
        },
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        },
```

Here, I'm using text for the datatype, as json errors out.

Is it OK to use text? How would I prep the JSON returned so jQuery likes it?

Comment: Your problem is the escaping get rid of all those \ and you should be fine

Comment: How is the JSON string being created inside the controller?  Can you post that code?

Comment: using JSON.NET like this: string jsonSettings = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Answer (score -1):

if you are expecting JSON to get returned, then you should also set your `$.ajax` datatype to JSON:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

if you do so, you don't even need `$.parseJSON`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var obj = data;
}
```

is enough

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that when I use json I get a parseError unexpected Token \ error. Not sure why.

Comment: @CarlGanz yes, because your string isn't valid JSON. your first string would be fine without the `\` (backslashes) in it.

Comment: Those are the escape characters to support the double quotes. The JSON on the server side is produced from XML by JSON.NET like this: string jsonSettings = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Comment: @CarlGanz yes, but i don't know why you would need to escape the double quotes. if you can get your script to respond with the same json string without the backslashes, you are fine.

Comment: do this or something: $.parseJSON(data.replace("\",""));